# Append Special Character with Double black Slash [\\] in String Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to append double `\\` in String I tried following code but no getting expected output.

```
        String c= "edX-NYIF+CR.5x";
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
        Matcher match= pt.matcher(c);
         while(match.find())
        {
            String s= match.group();
            c=c.replace("\\+", "\\\\"+"+");
          //  c=c.replaceAll("-", "-\\");
           // c=c.replaceAll("\\.", ".\\");

        }
```

**Input :**

```
edX-NYIF+CR.5x
```

**Expected Output:**

```
edX\\-NYIF\\+CR\\.5x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you may directly use `String#replaceAll` to match and replace multiple substrings with a regex of your choice. Also, `String#replace` does not accept regex, so your `c=c.replace("\\+", "\\\\"+"+");` would not work.

You may use

```
String c = "edX-NYIF+CR.5x";
System.out.println(c.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "\\\\\\\\$0"));
```

See the [Java online demo](https://ideone.com/ln8Dpe)

The `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` (or `"\\P{Alnum}"`) will match any char but a letter or digit, and then `"\\\\\\\\$0"` (=`\\\\$0` literal string) will replace the match with itself prepended with 2 literal backslashes. Note that a literal backslash (that is specified in a Java string literal using two consecutive backslashes) is a special regex escape char that must be doubled to specify a single backslash that will be put in the resulting string.

If you are confused with backslashes and in fact want to get single (not double) backslashes in the output, remove 4 backslashes from the replacement pattern, `.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "\\\\$0")`.